# Google Maps Places Autocomplete not considering bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I have an input field which I'm using for autosuggest. This works fairly well and I'm also limiting the AutoSuggest to specific bounds. However, the bounds are not getting considered by AutoSuggest. I have the following code

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
                var input = document.getElementById('userlocation');
                console.log(bounds);
                var options = {
                    bounds: bounds,
                    types: ['address']
                };
                autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
            });
```

bounds is a LatLngBounds object with the following data

> j: 38.15153503418
>   k: 37.81086730957

And

> j: 23.63938140869095
>   k: 23.958692550658952

which should are the bounds of athens and some more around there.

The problem I'm facing now, is, that, when I type in "Athen" I also get entries from Germany, Malyisa, New York etc. back containing the word Athens.

Anyone know something that's not going ok?

I also tried this

`autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);`

which didn't work and this also has the function to adjust the bounds when the user changes the bounds. But I don't want the viewport to be changed dynamically. How would I do that?

Comment: How are you creating the [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The bounds I get for Athens, Greece is;

```
  "geometry": {
    "bounds": {
      "Ea": {
        "A": 37.9488181,
        "j": 38.0328563
      },
      "va": {
        "j": 23.68698619999998,
        "A": 23.7896925
      }
```

The viewport is:

```
    "viewport": {
      "Ea": {
        "A": 37.9488181,
        "j": 38.0328563
      },
      "va": {
        "j": 23.68698619999998,
        "A": 23.7896925
      }
    }
```

Looks like you have the coordinates reversed in the [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) constructor.

[autocomplete example from the documentation modified to start limited to Greece (you can change the bias)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w6pbok66/1/)

[original reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch)

[autocomplete seach for hotels in Athens, Greece](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w6pbok66/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Old thread, but still there, so my 5 cts:

This is how I pass bounds to options

```
options.bounds = { east = eastLng, north = northLat, south = southLat, west = westLng };
```

No need of `google.maps.LatLngBounds`, this is a `LatLngBoundsLiteral`, very unwell documented, but it works quite well.